# select all rows from a table and inserting only distinct values into a database at another location in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have two databases at different location of similar structure, I want to select all the rows from one database table and insert only distinct values into another database table using C#.

Comment: What have you tried would be a wonderful start? Also what DBMS are you using, makes a great difference.

Comment: you can do this in pure SQL. why write an app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select into sql statement

```
SELECT * INTO TableName FROM [MS Access;PWD=password;DATABASE=C:\Docs\database2.mdb].TableName
```

Make sure the datatype is same for source and destination columns

Comment: will this insert only distinct values into second database?